# ionic serve can't build ionic.app.scss to ../www/css ionic.app.css

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sass

i use ionic sass,but when i run " ionic serve " it open a window show my page, but it not generate ionic.app.css file in css directory. what's the problem.
This is my gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

// gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
      gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

[ionic serve print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2zXh.png)
[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fpve.png)

The scss file code below

```css
/*
To customize the look and feel of Ionic, you can override the variables
in ionic's _variables.scss file.

For example, you might change some of the default colors:

$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #4a87ee !default;
$calm:                            #43cee6 !default;
$balanced:                        #66cc33 !default;
$energized:                       #f0b840 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef4e3a !default;
$royal:                           #8a6de9 !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;
*/
// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";

$positive:                        #red !default;
.bar-pink{
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just run the `gulp sass` command?

Comment: the scss file ionic.app.scss  no generate to  ionic.app.css

Comment: Could you perhaps share your whole .scss file, so we can check whether it compiles on our machines?

Comment: I posted the ionic.app.scss file below my question